# Using some other name for init in python

Tags: python, keyword

I am learning implementation of data structures using python. I realized that __init__ method is used as a constructor (I read that in C++), my doubt is

> can we use some other name like __loader__ instead of __init__ and get results?

Is init a keyword or just a convention like using single underscore in beginning of internally used variable names (ignoring its usage in *excluding its imports*)

Comment: Try it, and you'll tell us what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init__` is the method that will be called as part of the instantiation process of the object. If your object doesn't have a method by exactly that name, it won't be called during object instantiation. You can of course call any other method anytime later yourself manually, but it won't be part of the object instantiation.

It's not a keyword, but it's a *reserved method name* for a specific purpose. The same way you couldn't implement a custom comparison function as `__foobar__` instead of `__lt__` and still expect it to be called when doing `a < b`.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You can't because when instancing an object of your class, by default, method `object.__init__()` will be called (because by default your class inherit from `object`).

And if you want to initialize your object differently, you have to **override** this method. And the only way to override a parent class method in python is by defining a child method with the same name, so by defining `__init__()` in your class.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a *keyword*:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('__init__')
False
```

But neither is it just convention. The [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) states:

> Classes are callable. [...] The arguments of the call are passed to
>   `__new__()` and, in the typical case, to `__init__()` to initialize the new instance.

More details are available in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) for `__init__()`